# Prove that a group of order $351$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup for some prime $p$ dividing its order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that a group of order $351$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup for some prime $p$ dividing its order.

So we know $351=3^313$.

And so by the 3rd Sylow Theorem,

$n_3|13$   and   $n_3 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$

$n_{13}|27$ and $n_{13} \equiv \pmod{13}$

So $n_3 = 1, 13$ and $n_{13} = 1, 27$

So if $n_3 = 1$ we are done. It is unique and hence normal.

Similarly if $n_{13}=1$ we are done.

So now suppose $n_{13} \neq 1$

How do we show from here that a normal exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n_{13}=27$, then there are $12\times 27$ elements of order $13$. This leaves
only $27$ elements of order **not** $13$, just enough to make one Sylow $3$-subgroup.

Comment: Why are we multiplying 12 by 27?

Comment: To exclude the identity element.

Comment: @s_healy Each Sylow $13$-subgroup has $12$ elements of order $13$.

Comment: is it $12$ times $27$ because they all share the identity? and by elements you mean Sylow $13$ subgroups?

Comment: @cqfd is my above comment correct?

Comment: what if $n_3=13$? Wheres the contradiction @cqfd

Comment: @MyMathYourMath, almost: it's $12$ times $27$ because they all share the identity, ***only***.